# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'postqs_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

i have reply_qs table and postqs table.Postqs_id is foreign key in reply_qs table.when i tried to save the reply_qs form data in database,its showed this error.

ERROR:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'postqs_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `reply_qs` (`reply`, `postqs_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dd, , 2017-09-23 02:54:16, 2017-09-23 02:54:16))

how i can solve it? and please explain why im getting this error.

reply_qs model :

```
 protected $table = 'reply_qs';
 protected $fillable = ['reply'];

 public function postqs(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Postqs', 'postqs_id', 'id');
    }
```

postqs model :

```
  public function reply_qs(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Reply_qs');
    }
```

store function:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $reply = new Reply_qs();
  $reply->reply = $request->get('reply');
  $reply->postqs_id = $request->get('postqs_id');
  $reply->save();
```

migration:

```
   Schema::create('reply_qs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->text('reply');
        $table->timestamps('date');
       });

   DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
    Schema::table('reply_qs',function(Blueprint $table)
    {
     $table->integer('postqs_id')->unsigned();
     $table->foreign('postqs_id')->references('id')->on('postqs') -
     >onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Comment: Please add tags for the language and frameworks used since this isn’t just SQL directly to MySQL

Comment: Crazy question, but are you really getting data for `postqs_id`? Or is that NULL?

Comment: @cwallenpoole it is not null..

Comment: You have defined field as `not null` only in one table. You have to set those the same: both related fields (`id` from `reply_qs` and `postqs_id` from `Postqs` need to be of same kind - not null.

Comment: @Tpojka its already in NOT NULL in the table.

Comment: Do you have same data type set ( I.E. unique constraints in both tables' field)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your relationship.

In your reply_qs model:

```
public function postqs(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Postqs', 'postqs_id', 'id');
}
```